# Unity3D - Detect if Windows 10 Anniversary (version number)

Tags: c#, windows, unity-game-engine, mono, .net-2.0

Okay, here's the thing. Some users are experiencing this issue with our game: for those who do have Win10 Anniversary Update, the Xbox One controller mapping I did is working nice, but for those using a Win10 pre-Anniversary the controller axis mapping is completely messed up.

So, what I'm going to do is to check which version of Win10 they are using, and apply a different mapping for the XOne pad depending on the current OS version. But I'm a bit lost on one thing: how can I check by code whether their Win10 is Anniversary Update or not? `SystemInfo.operatingSystem` is of no use, since it is always returning "Windows 10 (10.0.0)".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 1. Idea (using System Namespace)

Did you try

```
Environment.OSVersion.ToString();
```

It is available since .NET 1.1 and returns a version number of the NT system. So for me, using a current Windows 10, it is

> Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0

For Windows 8 and Windows 8.1 (both) it will return

> Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.0.0

I have no "old" Windows 10 running at the moment - so I cannot test that.

### 2. Idea (Loading DLLs)

Check [1] - they import the kernel32.dll from the system and use is to gather detailed information about the system.

[1] http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/707502/Version-Helper-API-for-NET

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer :) I will try this out and let you know, but it seems perfect for my needs.

Comment: Sorry for delaying my answer. I ended up checking the DLLs, and it worked like a charm. Thanks a lot for your detailed answer post.